# Filtering for only integer/numeric values in a varchar field

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table with a member id column (non-PK) that should all be integers. But many are NULL or non-integer values with a mixture of letters, numbers, and other random characters (the field is of type varchar). I want to select only rows containing valid member id's (i.e. integers or only numeric values). I'm working in SQL Workbench. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you work with mysql-workbench on postgres?..

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm using.. the application says 'sql workbench' but I was told it used PostgreSQL(?) that's why I just tagged everything.

Comment: run `select version();` ?..

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1232

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm connecting to redshift, the syntax is

```
where column ~ '[0-9].+'
```

Comment: only thing is the regex expression skipped the record with value `1`, so in my case I changed it to `'[0-9]+'` (removed the `.`) in case it might help.
Still valuable answer